# OSX Terminal - application listed by 'which' does not run by default

Tags: macos, shell, ssh, terminal, path

I followed instructions [on this page](https://kitepwr.wordpress.com/2014/11/07/add-color-to-your-ssh-sessions-mac-osx/) to change the profile of the Mac terminal when I'm running SSH. The short explanation is that it puts a wrapper script in */usr/local/bin* that changes the colour then calls */usr/bin/ssh*. When I call this script with the full path it works perfectly, but when I call '*ssh*', it appears to use the regular application without the wrapper script.

When I call '*which ssh*', the result is '*/usr/local/bin/ssh*'. My PATH variable is '*/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin*', which looks fine for me. The wrapper script has executable permissions ('-rwxr-xr-x ').

What am I missing? Why would the regular ssh be called rather than than the wrapper script, given the '*which*' command points to the one that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to clear bash's program location cache.

```
hash -d ssh
```

Comment: Actually, the problem resolved itself before I saw your answer, so I couldn't  test it to prove that your solution. I'm going to accept it anyway. Thanks!